# Python Gmail Api: Email is not sending as the specified from

Tags: python, gmail-api

```
import httplib2
import os
from httplib2 import Http

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes


from apiclient import errors

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

#SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/'
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Quickstart'

def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print 'Storing credentials to ' + credential_path
    return credentials

def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

testMessage = CreateMessage('hey@gmail.com', 'johndoeisawesome@gmail.com', 'ENTER SUBJECT', 'ENTER EMAIL BODY')

testSend = SendMessage(service, 'me', testMessage)
```

i get email in johndoeisawesome@gmail.com as the email account that i enabled gmail api as, NOT `hey@gmail.com`

is that the correct behavior? 
Then, whats the point of filling out `'from'` in CreateMessage()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Gmail alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en) in the `From`-header,

```
From: myalias@gmail.com
```

You can follow [this guide](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) to set up an alias.

Comment: so how do you set up hey@gmail.com as a alias?

Comment: @ealeon Good question :) Edited the answer.